# ASP.NET MVC Validation Summary not displaying when form errors are present

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I have tried following other answers to questions such as this to no avail.

My issue is that I'm trying to bring back validation messages to my razor form but they are not appearing in the validation summary section.

The validation summary was constantly showing until I added the CSS at the end of my question. The ModelState is also being flagged as invalid in the controller and it is returning the dto (model) back to the view.

Form:

```
@model Application.ViewModels.ContactUsViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "Help", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Subject)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Subject, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", tabindex = 1 } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", tabindex = 2 } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <button type="submit" class="button-default-small"><h5 class="buttonText">SEND</h5></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please enter all required information.", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

View model:

```
public class ContactUsViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendEmail(ContactUsViewModel dto)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("HelpView", dto);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("HelpView");
}

public ActionResult HelpView()
{
    return View();
}
```

CSS:

```
.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: You don't have a `ContactUsViewModel` parameter in your `HelpView` method, and you dont return that ViewModel you don't have to your view.

Comment: Good point, will remove that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Included the following scripts to fix the issue:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```